# Solid layer in Powerpoint 2016 embedded video changes color, slightly

Tags: adobe-after-effects, color-reproduction, video, microsoft-powerpoint

I've exported a video from Adobe After Effects into .avi, as well as encoded to .mp4, .wmv, .m4v and other formats using Adobe Media Encoder. Since I can't get a transparent alpha layer to work, I've changed the background color of the video to match the color of the slide, but the video's background color is changing slightly.

This does NOT occur when I export an uncompressed .avi directly from After Effects, but that leads to ~1GB each video, which is unacceptable.

Some example frames:

1. [image]
2. [image]

Note that in frame two, the colors match, but in frame one, this is taken from the same video. Any help would be greatly appreciated!